# Add emoji to SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

How is the coding to insert the emoji into the SQL Server database so it doesn't become a sign `????`

I have changed the chart type to `NVARCHAR`. The following coding that I have used in VB.Net

```
Private Sub btbInput_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btbInput.Click
    Call Koneksi()
    Dim InputData As String = "insert into Perintah values ('" & txtPerintah.Text & "','" & txtRespon.Text & "')"
    Cmd = New SqlCommand(InputData, Conn)
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Perintah berhasil di input")
    Call KondisiAwal()
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a parameter, instead of concatenating a string for your insert - that will solve your problem. Also you should specify the columns you are inserting into.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: @Sumbupulsa, what don't you understand about the examples you found when you looked for yourself?